# My installation of apache hadoop with a SIngle Node results in an error when starting

Tags: hadoop

**I'm installing Apache Hadoop locally with just a single node.**

**I've configured everything, but when I start Hadoop, the following error appears:**

**command:**

`/usr/local/hadoop/sbin/start-all.sh`

**Erro:**

`WARNING: Attempting to start all Apache Hadoop daemons as hadoop-user in 10 seconds.'

'WARNING: This is not a recommended production deployment configuration.'

'WARNING: Use CTRL-C to abort.'

'Starting namenodes on [localhost]'

'pdsh@lucas-MS-7B84: localhost: rcmd: socket: Permission denied
Starting datanodes'

'pdsh@lucas-MS-7B84: localhost: rcmd: socket: Permission denied'

'Starting secondary namenodes [lucas-MS-7B84]'

'pdsh@lucas-MS-7B84: lucas-MS-7B84: rcmd: socket: Permission denied'

'Starting resourcemanager'

'Starting nodemanagers'

'pdsh@lucas-MS-7B84: localhost: rcmd: socket: Permission denied`

**i followed some patching of chagtp, which was to give me some necessary permissions that it claimed my hadoop-user didn't have, even though i thought i had given it enough permissions during setup and installation. His suggestions, which I implemented and which didn't solve my problem, were:**

**Add the hadoop-user to the hadoop group:**

`sudo usermod -aG hadoop hadoop-user`

**Add the hadoop-user user to the sudo group (if necessary):**

`sudo usermod -aG sudo hadoop-user`

**Log directory permissions:**

`sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/hadoop/logs sudo chown hadoop-user:hadoop /usr/local/hadoop/logs`

**Permissions on the HDFS data directories:**

`sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/hadoop/yarn_data/hdfs/namenode sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/hadoop/yarn_data/hdfs/datanode sudo chown -R hadoop-user:hadoop /usr/local/hadoop/yarn_data`

**Permissions on the ResourceManager logs directory:**

`sudo mkdir -p /var/log/hadoop-yarn sudo chown hadoop-user:hadoop /var/log/hadoop-yarn`

**Add hadoop-user to the hadoop and sudo groups:**

`sudo usermod -aG hadoop hadoop-user sudo usermod -aG sudo hadoop-user`

**Make sure that hadoop-user is correctly listed in the hadoop and sudo groups:**

`groups hadoop-user`

**That didn't solve it, I need to know how and why this is happening**